# AngularJs read json file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a tree which is created dynamically with json.There is a one controller and in this controller there is a json array.I use this json to create a tree,but i need to read this json from file externally.

**My controller;**

```
..........
$scope.myjson = 
{       
    "option1": [
        {   
            "child":[{"label":"Test1" },{"label":"Test2"}],
            "id": "option1"

        }
    ],

"option2": [
        {   
            "child":[{"label":"Test1.1",}],
            "id": "option2"
        }
    ],
   ...........
   }
```

**Json array reading part(In Controller);**

```
angular.forEach($scope.myjson, function(value, key) 
        {
         if (key === 'option1') 
                {
                for(var t=0;t<$scope.myjson[key][0].child.length;t++)
                    {
                     ......Somethings.........
                     }
                 }
```

I want to call json file and read it to create a tree.How can i call json file and read in angularjs?

Comment: Did you check `$http.get`?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i have tried $http.get  before but i could not solve the problem ,could you give me an example jsfiddle?

Comment: @user4773604 You can find example in the answer posted.

Answer (score 2):

Reading JSON in Angular is pretty straightforward with $http. Keep in mind that $http will return a promise, and you need to resolve it before processing.

Here is a sample code:

```
$http.get('assets/messages.json').then(function (data) {
            /** work with data **/
});
```

Comment: could you give me an example similar to my task

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp) you can get a complete tutorial regarding your problem. You just need to modify it in your way.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
</script>
```